# Azure Cloud shell fails to identify server. Throws error : Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource not found

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cloud-shell

I am trying to get firewall rules configured on an existing azure sql server.
I am using Azure Cloud shell to run the following command which results in an error.

~$ az sql server firewall-rule list --server mydbserver.database.windows.net --resource-group myresourcegroup

Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource 'mydbserver.database.windows.net' not found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.database.windows.net` should not be there. `myserver.database.windows.net` is the server's fully qualified DNS name, but in the API the server's "name" is just  `myserver`.

Comment: I tried server name without the suffix but I am getting the same error.          Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource 'mydbserver' not found.

Comment: The failure was because I have multiple subscriptions on Azure and my default subscription did not have the sql-server. I changed the subscription by using az account set --subscription and now the command to get firewall works

Comment: More over `Microsoft` kept updating commands, i faced a same problem because of command updates.

Comment: Man, you are a genius! That's very confusing in the API. You normally copy the whole value from the portal.. Thanks